# How to return the text in <span> by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the code, i am a beginner of jQuery. 
I found these code from online and it is a questionnaire. And i want to save those selected options but i don't know how to do it.

1. " $.fn.jRadio = function (settings)" i don't know what is this setting for.
2. "        var options = $.extend(_defaults, settings || {});" what is ||{}

(function ($) {
    'use strict';

```
   // <label class="u-radio" data-name="radio1">
   //     <input name="radio1" type="radio">
   // </label>
   // <label class="u-radio" data-name="radio1">
     //   <input name="radio1" type="radio">
   // </label>
   // <label class="u-radio" data-name="radio2">
   //     <input name="radio2" type="radio" checked>
   // </label>


$.fn.jRadio = function (settings) {
    /* 默认参数 */
    var _defaults = {
        checkedClass: "z-checked", // 选中状态类名
        onChange: function (element) {

        } // onchange回调，返回当前选中项DOM元素
    };

    var options = $.extend(_defaults, settings || {});
    var radios = this;

    radios.each(function () {
        var $radio = $(this);
        var _name = $(this).data("name");   // 组name值

        /*---- 初始化 ----*/
        // 是否选中以input:radio的选中状态为准,多个选中的话以最后一个为准
        if($radio.find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) {
            var $otherRadios = radios.filter("[data-name='" + _name + "']").not($radio);
            $radio.addClass(options.checkedClass);
            $otherRadios.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
            $otherRadios.find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
            //var str_ans = radios.filter('span[class="text"]').innerHTML
            //var $str_ans = $radio.find('span[class="text"]').prop("innerText")

        }

        /*---- 添加事件 ----*/
        $radio.on("change", function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass(options.checkedClass)) {
                $(this).addClass(options.checkedClass);
                radios.filter("[data-name='" + _name + "']").not($(this)).removeClass(options.checkedClass); // 切换状态
                options.onChange($(this));  // 回调

                //alert($str_ans)
            }
        });
    });
};

/**
 * 复选框
 *
 * `Html`
    <label class="u-checkbox">
        <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    </label>
 * `/Html`
 *
 * @param settings 用户设置参数
 */
$.fn.jCheckbox = function (settings) {
    /* 默认参数 */
    var _defaults = {
        checkedClass: "z-checked", // 选中状态类名
        onChange: function (element) {} // onchange回调，返回当前选中项DOM元素组
    };

    var options = $.extend(_defaults, settings || {});
    var checkboxes = this;

    checkboxes.each(function () {
        var $checkbox = $(this);

        /*---- 初始化 ----*/
        // 是否选中以input:checkbox的选中状态为准
        if($checkbox.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
            $checkbox.addClass(options.checkedClass);
        } else {
            $checkbox.removeClass(options.checkedClass);
        }

        /*---- 添加事件 ----*/
        $checkbox.on("change", function () {
            $(this).toggleClass(options.checkedClass);
            options.onChange($(this));
        });
    });
};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: `$.fn.jRadio = function (settings)` adds a function name jRadio to JQuery (looks like a plugin)

Comment: `||` stands for OR  ... `{}` creates an empty anonymous object

Comment: `if($radio.find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')) {` should be `if($(this).prop('checked') == true)`

Answer (score 0):

1) `$.fn.jRadio = function (settings)` creates a jquery function that can be used like `$('#elem').jRadio({})`

2) `var options = $.extend(_defaults, settings || {});" what is ||{}` is checking if the settings object exists or not. If not it will assign options with a combined object if settings and _defaults , else it will assign just _defaults to options

It merges the content of one object to another. If we pass two objects, second object properties are added to the first object / first parameter.